# Access root for newly installed MySQL on nitrousio box?

Tags: mysql, django, nitrousio

EDIT- Turns out to be a silly question. The solution:

`mysql -u root` Don't put a -p as there is no password for fresh installs of MySQL root.

Original Question:

Autoparts just came out recently on nitrous: http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/09/18/introducing-autoparts-for-nitrous-io.html
and I ran the command `$ parts install mysql` to install mySQL...works great!
Now, how do I access mysql to setup a root user or other users?

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE django_db;                                                                                           
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'django_db'    

mysql> GRANT ALL ON django_db.* TO 'djangouser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';                                                                                                                                                    
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'django_db'
```

I don't know how to access `mysql -u root -p`  because I don't know the root password, so I just used `mysql` to access the mysql from the terminal.

My end goal is to have the mysql setup on my box for a development and testing for my django web application.

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it. It helped me.